# R programming: how to choose a combination of a factor with varying numbers, with constraints and then optimize?

Tags: r, optimization, combinations, factors

I want to get every combination of team whose price < x from a data format that looks like:

```
       Position              Name Salary           GameInfo AvgPointsPerGame
  1       WR       Julio Jones   9300 Phi@Atl 07:10PM ET           21.293
  2       WR Odell Beckham Jr.   9200 NYG@Dal 08:30PM ET           26.417
  3       WR  Demaryius Thomas   9100 Bal@Den 04:25PM ET           22.812
  4       WR        Dez Bryant   8700 NYG@Dal 08:30PM ET           19.033
  5       QB     Aaron Rodgers   8600  GB@Chi 01:00PM ET           23.428
  6       WR    Calvin Johnson   8500  Det@SD 04:05PM ET           18.229
```

Let's say the team would consist of 1 QB, 3 WR, 2RB, and a flx. Is there a package I could look into that would help me select all these combinations for the data set? Or perhaps just some ideas I should look into. I just want some direction not a solution.

I thinking optimization with constraints would be the correct way about going about this, but to be honest I have no idea.

The constraints would look something like this.

```
 #constraint 1
 #price of team < 50,000
 max_price >= 50000

 #constraint 2
 #1qb


 #constraint 3
 #2rb
 #rb1!=rb2

#constraint 4
#3wr
#wr1!=wr2!=wr3

#constraint 5
#1flex
#flx!=wr1!=wr2!=wr3 && flx!=rb1!=rb2
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Position = c("WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", "QB", "WR", 
"RB", "RB", "RB", "QB"), Name = c("Julio.Jones", "Odell.Beckham.Jr.", 
"Demaryius.Thomas", "Dez.Bryant", "Aaron.Rodgers", "Calvin.Johnson", 
"LeSean.McCoy", "Eddie.Lacy", "Jamaal.Charles", "Peyton.Manning"
), Salary = c(9300, 9200, 9100, 8700, 8600, 8500, 8300, 8200, 
8400, 9100), GameInfo = c("Phi@Atl.07:10PMET", "NYG@Dal.08:30PMET", 
"Bal@Den.04:25PMET", "NYG@Dal.08:30PMET", "GB@Chi.01:00PMET", 
"Det@SD.04:05PMET", "GB@Chi.01:00PMET", "GB@Chi.01:00PMET", "GB@Chi.01:00PMET", 
"GB@Chi.01:00PMET"), AvgPointsPerGame = c(21.293, 26.417, 22.812, 
19.033, 23.428, 18.229, 21.24, 21.24, 21.24, 21.24)), .Names = c("Position", 
"Name", "Salary", "GameInfo", "AvgPointsPerGame"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There is too much info to digest and the problem is not clear. It seems like you just want all unique combinations. Look into the unique function. If that is not what you want you need to state the problem much more simply with a simpler example.

Comment: It would probably help to focus on Position and Salary columns. They are the only two that matter for the constrain function.